# JS: Call async function before exporting something

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-modules, ecmascript-next

I need to call an async function to get my auth token. In an export, I want to include the returned value from this fn.

My first try:

```
const token = await sessionHandler.getToken();

export const httpService = axios.create({
    ...
    headers: {
        "auth-token": token
        ...
    }
});
```

Of course this doesn't work because the `await` is not in a async function.
So I could just wrap this in an async function, right? No, because I'd have to use callbacks. Then again I wouldn't have the export on top-level which doesn't work either.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why do you have the requirement to not use callbacks? Is that a requirement you set yourself or because you don't know how to solve it with callbacks?

Comment: @t.niese Exports have to be top-level

Comment: seems like you're trying to turn something asynchronous into something synchronous - is that what you're asking?

Comment: I still don't get it. An http request where you use an auth token, ist async, so why can't you request the auth token at demand the first time it is required?

Comment: The token will be used with every call in the axios instance, so I want to first get the token and then export the service

Comment: I don't get why you would need to use callbacks for an `async function`? The whole purpose is that it will return a promise that you can `await` without any callback usage.

Comment: @Bergi An export has to be top level. Can you explain me how I can make a top level export with getting async data before?

Comment: @Sandrooco Export the promise or export the async function, like in Quentins answer. In neither case would you use any callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `httpService` must not be async then I would use `interceptors` for this kind of requirement, if the token is not ready at the first request, then then the interceptor will wait until the promise is fulfilled. The token will be requested only once.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const token = sessionHandler.getToken();

export const httpService = axios.create({
  ...
  headers: {
    ...
  }
});

httpService.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  return token.then(token => {
    config.headers['auth-token'] = token;
    return config;
  })
}, function(error) {
  console.dir(error)
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

**EDIT** Personally I prefer if data is only requested on demand and not on include so I would use a slightly different version:

```
const axios = require('axios')
let token;

export const httpService = axios.create({
  ...
  headers: {
    ...
  }
});

httpService.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  token = token || sessionHandler.getToken(); //request it only if not already requested.

  return token.then(token => {
    config.headers['auth-token'] = token;
    return config;
  })
}, function(error) {
  console.dir(error)
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: @Sandrooco why do you believe that it request the token every time?

Comment: Because the interceptor intercepts all request and not just one?!

Comment: @Sandrooco yes, but the request of the token is only done once, the first time the file is executed. The _top level_  `token` variable  stores the Promise. You can call `.then` on the promise as often as you want, this will not start a new request, it will just wait until the Promise is resolved. `getToken` does the request and returns a Promise. The Promise just stores a state (waiting, the fulfilled value or the rejection error)

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't think about that. Works perfectly!

Comment: @Sandrooco no problem. The more you use Promises the more you get used to it

Comment: @Sandrooco I added an edit just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible.
Exports must be defined in a synchronous manner and you cannot wait for something before exporting.

What I suggest is that you export an async function. If you do not want the token to be requested each time, you might consider saving it:

```
let token;

export const createHttpService = async () => {
  token = token == null ? await sessionHandler.getToken() : token;
  return axios.create({
    /* ... */
    headers: {
        "auth-token": token
        /* ... */
    }
  });
};
```

However, if this is acceptable for you, I think I would prefer to separate the request of this token and let the consumer of the module passing it back to `createHttpService` (and thus being responsible of saving it).

```
export const getToken = () => sessionHandler.getToken();

export const createHttpService = (token) => {
  return axios.create({
    /* ... */
    headers: {
        "auth-token": token
        /* ... */
    }
  });
};
```

Alternatively you may directly export the promise if you really want to require the token upon module loading. However, I would recommend to be wary of side-effects upon module loading.

Comment: Interesting, how would you call it later?

Comment: I don't want it to get a new token with any request though?!

Comment: I see, in this case, you might want to save that token.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. The consumer will be `createHttpService().get(...)`?

Comment: No, `createHttpService` (first version) will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (like any async function). [Here is a nice article about promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

Comment: I understand how promises work but not how I could use this service.. :)

Comment: You can do `createHttpService().then((service) => { /* stuff */ });` or inside an async function `const serve = await createHttpService();`. Again that is you opt for the first version but if I were you I would rather use the second.